# what functionalities should a web server at least have?

Tags: linux, http, web, http-headers

what functionalities should a web server at least have?

And in order to implement a web server, what protocols should be read and understood first?

Answer (score 0):

A web server almost by definition has to serve a website.

Websites are served by the HTTP protocol.

This is explained in detail in [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).

Note: This is HTTP/1.1 rather than 1.0, but literally no one uses HTTP/1.0.

HTTP is a reasonable simple request response protocol, and has been expanded by a huge number of extensions over the years.

It is also being succeeded by HTTP/2.0, which is significantly more complex.

Comment: 2616 is obsoleted.